# ioS Swift New users unable to login until app is terminated and launch

Tags: ios, swift, oop, singleton, keychain

I have a very weird issue to me right now. Initially I thought it has to do with realm, cos I was initially persisting auth token in realm. I eventually had to move it keychain. The issue is this - when a new user signup successfully an auth token is saved to keychain for resuse to hit authenticated end point. However for every new users that signup and tries to make request to an authenticated route, it keeps saying invalid auth token. But the moment the new user terminates the app and relaunch it the error goes away and the new user who was previously unable to make request to authenticated end point will now be able to. I have research the root countless number of times and still no head way I will appreciate your support and pointers to resolved this issue. when i print the auth token from key chain the moment the user is making the request, the token is available. this is how I am retrieving the token from keychain

```
  class UserData {

static let instance  = UserData()
private init() {}

func userAuthToken() -> String {
    guard let authToken = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: Const.authToken) else { return ""}
    return authToken
}

func userisAuthenticated() -> Bool {
    guard let isEnabled = KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: Const.isEnabled) else { return false}
    return isEnabled
}

func userRefreshToken() -> String {
    guard let refreshToken = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: Const.refreshToken) else { return ""}
    return refreshToken
}
}
```

this is the code for saving to keychain at the time of signup

```
      KeychainWrapper.standard.set(true, forKey: Const.isEnabled)
      KeychainWrapper.standard.set("2308r20390f", forKey: Const.authToken)
      KeychainWrapper.standard.set("2729894820", forKey: Const.refreshToken)
```

Comment: please can you share code of save token after sign up

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish many thaanks i have added use to save to keychain

Comment: are you use Token in header request or  Basic authentication

Comment: token in header request

Comment: On app launch are you using the refresh token to get a new auth token ? You need to put breakpoints on setting and retrieving the tokens to see exactly what values you have when you call the API.  Can you confirm that you have the same values in the header before and after the user kills the app?

Comment: @wottle yes i do have thesame token both before and after.i kill the app. the refresh is for use when the auth token expires

Comment: So in your HTTP header you are passing the same auth token and getting an unauthorized before killing the app, but a 200 after the app has been relaunched?  That seems unlikely.  Are you sure there are no other header value differences?

Answer (score 0):

May be you call API in `signup process` that store default value to token , in request and not change to new saved one until you close app and open again ,
so you have to change API Manager to deal with this point.

*to Test this try to use any token in Any api before Signup process*

Comment: am not clear with your explanation. i dont have default saved. Why cant i access save token  from keychain untial app is relaunched

Comment: i don't mean this i say your request of API Manager during sign app have no token , it continue with this state until you relaunch app again to read saved one

Comment: send m API manager request or Just create any Alamofire request after sign up and it will work with you if i correct

Comment: I am actually making a request after a user signup. I am using Moya with rx swift by the way